# Closed non-exact $2$-form on $T = S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I would like to find a closed non-exact $2$-form on $T = S^1 \times S^1$.

Here are my thoughts:

Since $d\theta$ and $d\varphi$ are closed non-exact $1$-forms an obvious candidate is $d\theta \wedge d \varphi$. This is closed since

$$ d(d\theta \wedge d \varphi) = d\theta \wedge d \varphi \wedge d \theta + d\theta \wedge d \varphi \wedge d \varphi = 0$$

> But how can I show that it is not exact?

(I'm sure it is indeed not exact)

I had the idea that by contradiction assume that it is exact. Then by Stokes' theorem

$$ \int_T d\theta \wedge d \varphi = \int_T d \psi = \int_{\partial T} \psi = \int_\varnothing \psi = 0$$

But I don't see why this should be a contradiction...

Comment: I guess because it involves angle and so the integration will definitely be path-dependent so it's not exact? Not sure of my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a contradiction, show by some other means that the integral is nonzero. Since $d\theta \wedge d\phi$ is in fact the standard volume form on $T$, this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I know that $d\theta \wedge d \varphi$ is "the volume form of the torus" which probably means that integrating over it yields the surface are but I don't know how to actually prove it.

Comment: Since $T=S^1\times S^1$, Fubini's Theorem tells you that $$\int_T d\theta\wedge d\phi = \left(\int_{S^1} d\theta\right)\left(\int_{S^1} d\phi\right) = (2\pi)^2.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin But the comment shortly before theorem 2.6.1. in this book [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tdF8uTn2cnMC&lpg=PA55&ots=vyedK0UFKP&dq=fubini%20theorem%20exterior%20product&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q=fubini%20theorem%20exterior%20product&f=false) seems to suggest that $d(x,y)\neq dx \wedge dy$ so how can you apply Fubini here? Is there another version of the Fubini theorem for wedge products?

Comment: Check the definitions carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin Which? Of $dx \wedge dy$ or of $dx dy$?

Comment: Of how you integrate $f dx_1\wedge \dots dx_n$ over $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm now googling for "differential n-form on R^n" but nothing useful so far. Would you give me a direction on what to look for?